# File access and retrieval within an android library

Tags: android

There must be some sort of small technical error that I am performing here that I cannot get a grasp on.  The file is in the raw/ directory of the AndroidLibrary, and access to different files are being used just fine in this manner.  Perhaps there is a slight error here that I keep glazing over?

**Note:** The raw resource is in an uncompressed format so that it can be read in with a .jet extension so that there are not any complaints by the internal file system.

**Edit (Update):** Apparently in order to get the stream open, the openRawResourceFd was not enough.  In addition to that I needed to call assetDescriptor.createInputStream();  If I did not, the stream would not behave properly.  Odd, as I would expect the openRawResourceFd to do the trick.

```
        AssetFileDescriptor assetDescriptor = resources.openRawResourceFd(com.grubulon.R.raw.testing_patches);
        BufferedReader bufferedInputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(assetDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()));

        colorSpace = bufferedInputStream.readLine();

        while ((currentLine = bufferedInputStream.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            rgbValues = currentLine.split("\\t");
            red = Integer.parseInt(rgbValues[0]);
            green = Integer.parseInt(rgbValues[1]);
            blue = Integer.parseInt(rgbValues[2]);
            rgbPatches.add(new RgbColorValue(red, green, blue));
        }

        bufferedInputStream.close();
        assetDescriptor.close();
```

The file itself is really only an Excel spreadsheet of RGB color values that are being read in with tabs in between them.  The tab component does not seem to be the issue, but the first line is a garble of lots and lots of text.  Not the color space, or values at all for that matter.  I am not sure what is going on here.

File example:

```
RGB
0   0   0
17  17  17
34  34  34
51  51  51
68  68  68
85  85  85
102 102 102
119 119 119
136 136 136
153 153 153
170 170 170
187 187 187
204 204 204
221 221 221
238 238 238
255 255 255
255 0   0
0   255 0
0   0   255
```

The following is an example of what is coming across in the Logcat even though there should be very little text coming across from the file.

[image: Logcat Window]

Answer (score 0):

The following based upon the update above is what has resolved the problem. Notice the line after the assetDescriptor is created with the openRawResourceFd call.

```
    AssetFileDescriptor assetDescriptor = resources.openRawResourceFd(com.grubulon.R.raw.testing_patches);
    assetDescriptor.createInputStream();
    BufferedReader bufferedInputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(assetDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()));

    colorSpace = bufferedInputStream.readLine();

    while ((currentLine = bufferedInputStream.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        rgbValues = currentLine.split("\\t");
        red = Integer.parseInt(rgbValues[0]);
        green = Integer.parseInt(rgbValues[1]);
        blue = Integer.parseInt(rgbValues[2]);
        rgbPatches.add(new RgbColorValue(red, green, blue));
    }

    bufferedInputStream.close();
    assetDescriptor.close();
```